# Conditional import in Objective-C depending on the architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, frameworks, cpu-architecture

I have a precompiled library which is only available as `arm64` framework. I'd like to import it when possible and import another version the library if target is `armv7`.

How can I achieve this with Objective-C?

I'm looking for something similar to this pseudocode:

```
if arm64 || x86_64 {
#import <LibraryArm64>
} else {
#import <Library32>
}
```

**Updated:**

This code gives result that's close enough for me:

```
#if __LP64__
#import <A.h>
#else
#import "B.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Does Objective C still use the C preprocessor?  `#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__aarch64__)`  [What predefined macro can I use to detect the target architecture in Clang?](//stackoverflow.com/q/23934862)

Comment: Should do, could you write the complete answer?

Comment: Another trick you can use is `#if UINTPTR_MAX > (1ULL << 32)` to detect targets with 64-bit pointers, if you don't mind `#include <stdint.h>`  (at least in C / C++, I don't know Objective C at all.)   BTW, normally you shouldn't edit an answer into your question.  Post it as an answer.  (If it's not a good answer, hopefully people will comment and/or vote to let you know, and/or post a better answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Another viable option you have is to use Xcode project settings to define a custom preprocessor flag of your liking. You can also use this to control linker flags as well.

It would look something like this in Build Settings.

[image]

The only "gotcha" is that with more recent versions of Xcode you need to "help" Xcode out with doing this manually. When you first try and add an architecture or SDK (Click on the + icon at the far right of the Configuration setting value), it will only show "Any Architecture | Any SDK".

[image]

You then have to edit the project.pbxproj and search for "arch=*". Then you can replace this with your architecture. For example it would look like the following in the project.pbxproj file.

```
            "GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL[arch=*]" = s;
```

After this, you will see it show up properly in Xcode (like my first example).